# TCP reverse proxy in C for bypassing NAT

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, embedded

I'm working on a project that requires an ESP32 microcontroller to act as a server, which needs to be accessed by clients from anywhere. However, the ESP32 is located behind my network provider's NAT, which means it doesn't have a public IP. To solve this problem, I've decided to use a VPS as a gateway for reverse proxying requests from clients.

I understand the concept of reverse proxying, but I'm having trouble writing the networking code for both the ESP32 server and the VPS gateway. The ESP32 program will be written in C using lwIP (usual BSD sockets), and the gateway program will also be in C.

I've found [this](https://github.com/aploium/shootback) thing, but it's in Python and it uses a custom protocol on top of TCP, so I don't know how to apply it to my problem.

My question is, how can I make the ESP32 server communicate with the VPS gateway to forward requests from clients through it? Can you provide some code examples or point me to some relevant documentation to help me get started? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You typically proxy through a VPS if your clients need accept connections but they're behind a restricted NAT. In which case you provide the VPS for them to tunnel through.

Comment: If you're hosting the server, but it's behind NAT then proxying your own server through a VPS seems to defeat the purpose..

Comment: @Irelia I need a reverse proxy because my server (ESP32) is not accesible from clients (located in a private network). I just have a VPS and I want the ESP32 to process requests not only from my home network, but also from any location

Comment: So you need your VPS on your home network to relay traffic between your clients and your ESP32?

Comment: The VPS is not on my home network (it has a public IP), but the ESP32 is.

Comment: [that's](https://samy.pl/pwnat/) what I seemingly needed